# Shadowbox PHP Facebook Graph Api Error

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, shadowbox

i'm using shadowbox for my website to open the big images with clicking thumbnails as you know. My Problem is, i'm fetching the users' facebook profile photo like :

```
$large = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$id2}/picture?type=large";
$small = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$id2}/picture?type=square";
```

And it's working perfect, but in shadowbox i have problem with large image..

I'm calling this in shadowbox like :

```
<a href="<?php echo $large; ?>" rel="shadowbox">
<img style="max-width:50px; max-height:50p;" src="<?php echo $small; ?>" />
</a>
```

As you can imagine, small image is showing perfect, but when i click on the small image which has href, it fails to show the large image.

I've tried to change large image variable to this :

```
$large = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$id2}/picture?type=large&redirect=false";
```

but also it has failed to show the large image..

Hope you can help, thank you

Comment: What's the sample value of $id2? And the sample value of $large?

Comment: Can you confirm that you're even getting a URL back?  If you aren't then there's a problem with your PHP.  If you are and it's just not displaying correctly then you've got a problem with the Javascript related to Shadowbox.

Comment: $id2 is the value of the user's id who has logged into my website with facebook, also i don't get url back, tried both with redirect false and the normal one but both have not worked

Comment: can you double check if it works if it is just url to the image?

Comment: `<a href="https://graph.facebook.com/*******/picture?type=large" rel="shadowbox"><img style="max-width:50px; max-height:50px;" src="https://graph.facebook.com/*******/picture?type=normal" />******</a>` This is how the browser shows and as i said bigger image hasn't get shown..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with Shadowbox before, so I don't know how it works behind the scenes. It may be that it can't deal with a url that returns another url for the large image.

Try making the API call with php and then passing this result to shadowbox.

```
$large = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/{$id2}/picture?type=large&redirect=false");
```

Of course, using `file_get_contents()` like this is a quick and dirty method. If it works, before you roll this out to a production site, you'll want to use `cURL` or better yet the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php) to do this.

Assuming you're using shadowbox to show multiple users' photos on a page, you'll probably end up bumping into the API limits at some point. To prevent this, redo your API calls to grab multiple photos in one shot:

```
$large_photos = $fb->api('/picture?type=large&redirect=false&ids=' . 
                           implode($ids_array, ','));
```

Comment: thank you @cpilko, that got the full url but doesnt show again because of the fetching the url false, even i don't make input sanitiziation with inserting and the db row is the same.          output is :



`<a href=""https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-snc7\/*****_******" rel="shadowbox">`

Comment: also i'm using pdo with database actions, if its the problem, how can i prevent that ? or preg_replace and things like that would work ?

Comment: Try running your variable through [stripslashes()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Comment: added that now adding to database better but still problem there is 

`"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc7/372309_802399776_165`

there is a `"` mark unnecessary, and this is how i call now

`<a href="<?php echo stripslashes($large); ?>" rel="shadowbox">`

Comment: You should look to see where that `"` is getting added. For the time being you could remove it with `substr($string,1);`

Comment: thank you for response, fixed that too but now figured out it doesnt parse all the url, it parses only some `https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc7/372309_802399776_165` the some numbers and .jpg is missing, why that can be

edit : found out the reason of this : its because of the database rows' length

Comment: Is your db field the correct type and large enough to hold the data you're trying to store in it?

Comment: yes i figured it out while typing the comment, thank you for being patient and answering my question :)

Answer (score 0):

`https://graph.facebook.com/{$id2}/picture?type=large&redirect=false` basically returns you a text content the URL of the image. That's why it's not showing.

Eg.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/yungsenriady.budiman.3/picture?type=large&redirect=false
```

returns

```
"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/157348_100001167523294_1569184886_n.jpg"
```

Try just use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{$id2}/picture?type=large
```